# Odoo routes gives "Internal Server Error" error page

Tags: xml, python-3.x, ubuntu, odoo-11

I'm learning Odoo 11 python developement on Ubuntu by creating a new custom module, from a Youtube video, its code is available on github.

I copied the same project (https://github.com/mtsoftware2016/Odoo-First-Model), everything is working fine except for routes.

controllers.py :

```
from odoo import http

class MyfirstModel(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/home', auth='public')
    def home(self, **kw):
        return 'Hello world'

    @http.route('/example', type='http', auth='public', website=True)
    def render_example_page(self):
        customer = http.request.env['customer'].sudo().search([])
        return http.request.render('myfirst_model.example_page', {'customers': customer})
```

Here the /home route is working, but /example gives this error message on page:

**Internal Server Error**

*The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.*

Odoo errors log:

```
2018-10-25 10:33:58,858 4933 INFO odoo3 werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [25/Oct/2018 10:33:58] "GET /example HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2018-10-25 10:33:58,880 4933 ERROR odoo3 werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 270, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 258, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 250, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 166, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 154, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1318, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1292, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 766, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1490, in dispatch
    result = ir_http._dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/web_editor/models/ir_http.py", line 22, in _dispatch
    return super(IrHttp, cls)._dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 212, in _dispatch
    return cls._handle_exception(e)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 182, in _handle_exception
    return request._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 770, in _handle_exception
    return super(HttpRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 208, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 829, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 342, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 338, in checked_call
    result.flatten()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1269, in flatten
    self.response.append(self.render())
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1262, in render
    return env["ir.ui.view"].render_template(self.template, self.qcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1201, in render_template
    return self.browse(self.get_view_id(template)).render(values, engine)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/web_editor/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 27, in render
    return super(IrUiView, self).render(values=values, engine=engine)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1210, in render
    return self.env[engine].render(self.id, qcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/ir_qweb.py", line 57, in render
    return super(IrQWeb, self).render(id_or_xml_id, values=values, **context)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 272, in render
    self.compile(template, options)(self, body.append, values or {})
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 345, in _compiled_fn
    raise e
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 343, in _compiled_fn
    return compiled(self, append, new, options, log)
  File "<template>", line 1, in template_236_3

  File "<decorator-gen-37>", line 2, in compile

  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 89, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/ir_qweb.py", line 77, in compile
    return super(IrQWeb, self).compile(id_or_xml_id, options=options)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 289, in compile
    element, document = self.get_template(template, options)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 373, in get_template
    raise QWebException("load could not load template", name=template)
odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb.qweb.QWebException: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 84, in lookup
    r = d[key]
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/func.py", line 68, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: ('ir.qweb', <function IrQWeb.compile at 0x7f10b987f9d8>, 'website.layout', ('en_US', None, None, None, None, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 84, in lookup
    r = d[key]
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/func.py", line 68, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: ('ir.model.data', <function IrModelData.xmlid_lookup at 0x7f10ba819620>, 'website.layout')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 369, in get_template
    document = options.get('load', self.load)(template, options)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/ir_qweb.py", line 85, in load
    template = env['ir.ui.view'].read_template(name)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1096, in read_template
    return self._read_template(self.get_view_id(xml_id))
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1108, in get_view_id
    return self.env['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_res_id(template, raise_if_not_found=True)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1343, in xmlid_to_res_id
    return self.xmlid_to_res_model_res_id(xmlid, raise_if_not_found)[1]
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1334, in xmlid_to_res_model_res_id
    return self.xmlid_lookup(xmlid)[1:3]
  File "<decorator-gen-21>", line 2, in xmlid_lookup
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 89, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1323, in xmlid_lookup
    raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
ValueError: External ID not found in the system: website.layout

load could not load template
Template: website.layout
```

example_page view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="example_page" name="Customer Details">
        <t t-call="website.layout">
            <center>
                <h>Customer Details</h>
            </center>
        </t>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the problem by installing the Odoo website module.